# zsh: killed in Terminal

Tags: macos, zsh, mongodb, macos-ventura

After trying to install `mongoDB` on macOS Ventura, I'm getting error `zsh: killed`.

- When I open Terminal, I see:

  ```zsh
  zsh: killed mkdir -m 700 -p "$SHELL_SESSION_DIR"
  ```
- Whenever I try to run a command, the same problem occurs:

  ```zsh
  Desktop % ls
  zsh: killed ls
  ```

I've checked my system's resources and there doesn't seem to be any limitations or constraints, and have also verified I have sufficient disk space available.

How do I identify the cause of this error and resolve it?

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved. I have been facing the same since yesterday

Comment: Can you give more details on how you are trying to install MongoDB? What commands or actions have you taken?